# React js source code

Tags: reactjs

I was reading `react.js` source code and came across this function inside `forwardRef.js`. Couldn't understand the function name part,

```
export default function forwardRef<Props, ElementType: React$ElementType>(
 render: (props: Props, ref: React$ElementRef<ElementType>) => React$Node,
) {
if (__DEV__) {
warning(
  typeof render === 'function',
  'forwardRef requires a render function but was given %s.',
  render === null ? 'null' : typeof render,
);

if (render != null) {
  warning(
    render.defaultProps == null && render.propTypes == null,
    'forwardRef render functions do not support propTypes or defaultProps. ' +
      'Did you accidentally pass a React component?',
  );
 }
}
```

What exactly is `forwardRef<Props, ElementType: React$ElementType>`? Is this the function name? Why does it look like that?

Comment: I believe this is how `flow` looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how generic functions are defined in `flow`. Have a look [here](https://alligator.io/flow/flow-generics/)